# Why is my http error response not being called when img ng-src is called?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have the following problem: I am trying to trap an HTTP 500 response from the server but the intercept is not getting the 500 response. This is generated by an img src call to an unauthorized URL (technically the server should be returning a 4xx, but it returns a 5xx --> its a 3rd party server.

**Update 2:** My intercept with HTTP rejection *is* called if I do a direct $http.get but it does not get called if the http get is implicitly called by img ng-src or img-src. The funny part is my httptimeout intercept is called, but the response intercept is never called. How do I solve this?

**Update 1**: I've added a screenshot of the 500 error that is being received by my browser via web inspector but not being intercepted. Please see the end.

interceptor code:

```
  .factory('timeoutHttpIntercept', function ($rootScope, $q) {
            //console.log("*** HTTP INTERCEPTOR CALLED ***");
            return {
                'request': function (config) {
                    config.timeout = 15000;
                    //console.log("*** HTTP INTERCEPTOR CALLED ***");
                    return config;
                }


            };
        })

.factory ('httpAuthIntercept', function ($rootScope, $q)
{
    return {
    requestError: function (response) {
      console.log ("**** REJECT REQUEST: "+JSON.stringify(response));
      return $q.reject(response);
    },

    responseError: function (response) {
      console.log ("**** REJECT RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(response));
      return $q.reject(response);
    },
    response: function (response)
        {
            console.log("*******RESPONSE with status: "+response.status+"****************");
            if (response.status == 500)
            {
             console.log ("**** RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(response));
            }
                return (response);
        }
  };
})
```

Followed by, in .config:

```
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutHttpIntercept');
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpAuthIntercept');
```

Now, in my template  I am calling the following code:

`<img  ng-src="{{LoginData.url}}/cgi-bin/zms?mode=jpeg&amp;monitor={{monitorId}}&maxfps=3&buffer=1000&auth=1234&rand={{rand}}" width="100%" />`

The above triggers a 500 response. I see the server logs generating this as well:

```
Starting capture on eth0 interface
2015-05-11 05:12:44 xx.xx.xx.xx 192.168.1.13    >   GET <server.com>    /cgi-bin/zms?mode=jpeg&monitor=1&maxfps=3&buffer=1000&auth=1234&rand=116426 HTTP/1.1    -
2015-05-11 05:12:44 192.168.1.13    xx.xx.xx.xx <   -   -   -   HTTP/1.1    500 Internal Server Error
```

But for some reason, the auth intercept is not trapping this 500. If I remove the 500 check in auth intercept, I can see it trapping successful responses with 200 OK.

What am I doing wrong?

500 Response screenshot being received --> web inspector of Safari:

[image: 500 error being received]

Thanks

Comment: you should do 500 status check in `responseError` and not in `response`

Comment: entre, my problem is responseError is never called when the server returns 500 & actually, nor is the response handler called.

Comment: then try `requestError`, it seems your request is not reaching to server or your interceptor is not registered

Answer (score 0):

Whats the angularjs version you are using? if its < 1.3 it may be worth trying to pushing your interceptor to **`$httpProvider.responseInterceptors`** instead on **`$httpProvider`**

```
app.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(function (response) {
                return response;
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response.status === 500) {
                    // you should hit this for HTTP 500
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
    });


app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

   // rest of the config code

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');
})
```

another implementation

```
app.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', ['$q', function ( $q) {
    function success(response) {
        // all good
    return response;
    }
    function error(response) {
        var status = response.status;
        if (status == 500) {
            return;
        }
        // otherwise
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Chintana, thanks. I am using 1.3.15.
This is quite perplexing -- my response interceptor is being called for 200 responses, just not for 500 (I don't know if will be called for 4xx as the server does not send 4xx). 

I can even see the 500 internal server via web console in Safari - so the response is being received, but not intercepted

Comment: I've also added a snapshot of the 500 response being received by the client browser if it helps

Comment: Its very strange indeed.. for what its worth, I have included a different implementation of the interceptor. Please take a look at it and see whether it works for you - cheers

Comment: I've updated my code - on further debugging, http interceptors don't seem to be called when I am implicitly calling http get from img-src. If I directly called http.get it does get called. Any ideas how to intercept img-src?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

My responseError method of the interceptor wasn't triggered after generating an 500 error with Fiddler (proxy). In fiddler you can create your own responses for certain files. The problem somehow was in my own created response. Not sure where the problem was. But after I copied one of the responses allready in Fiddler I got the method responseError working.

Perhaps the response you are getting from the third party server is invalid somehow.

If you want to try with Fiddler. In the programm folder you have certain ResponseTemplates
C:\Program Files\Fiddler2\ResponseTemplates

Copied "502_unreachable.dat" to "500_servererror.dat" and only modified the response code to 500 and left response body untouched.

restarted Fiddler and I could apply my new created Fiddler response as auto-responder. 
And yes it triggered the responseError method.